# Not able to switch to the frame in the page of the timeofindia site

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

```
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;

import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class TimeOfIndiaElements {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        WebDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.get("http://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/");
        WebElement  element=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//form[@name='pollform']"));
        driver.switchTo().frame(element");
        String mathText=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='pdiv']//span[@id='mathq2']")).getText();
        System.out.println(mathText);
    }

}
```

I am not able to switch to the frame(containing 5+5) in the timesofindia site and getting `NoSuchElementException`. Kindly help me as am new to selenium.

Answer (score 0):

The frame seems to be:

```
<iframe id="mailroifrm12" width="300" scrolling="no" align="left" height="223" frameborder="0" src="/poll.cms" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" hspace="0" vspace="0" valign="top">
```

so try to :

```
    WebElement  element=driver.findElement(By.id("mailroifrm12"));
    driver.switchTo().frame(element);
    WebElement  form =driver.findElement(By.xpath("//form[@name='pollform']"));
    // do stuff
```

Comment: how do i recognize frames on the page?